# Editing tables with R studio

Tags: dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation, phyloseq

| Phylum | Abundance |
| --- | --- |
| Bacteroidetes | 12 |
| Firmicutes | 4 |
| Proteobacteria | 3 |
| Firmicutes | 21 |
| Firmicutes | 9 |
| Bacteroidetes | 15 |
| Proteobacteria | 3 |
| Bacteroidetes | 8 |
| Verrucomicrobia | 2 |
| Bacteroidetes | 5 |

My question is I have a table like above in R studio. I want to write this table by combining the similar ones in the Phylum column in a new table and by adding the Abundance column while doing this, but I couldn't find a way. Sample output;

| Phylum | Abundance |
| --- | --- |
| Firmicutes | 34 |
| Bacteroidetes | 40 |
| Proteobacteria | 6 |
| Verrucomicrobia | 2 |

Can you help me find the code that will allow me to output the above?
Thank you from now.

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(Phylum = c("Bacteroidetes","Firmicutes","Proteobacteria","Firmicutes","Firmicutes","Bacteroidetes","Proteobacteria","Bacteroidetes","Verrucomicrobia","Bacteroidetes"),
                 Abundance = c(12,4,3,21,9,15,3,8,2,5))


df

           Phylum Abundance
1    Bacteroidetes        12
2       Firmicutes         4
3   Proteobacteria         3
4       Firmicutes        21
5       Firmicutes         9
6    Bacteroidetes        15
7   Proteobacteria         3
8    Bacteroidetes         8
9  Verrucomicrobia         2
10   Bacteroidetes         5

aggregate(Abundance~.,df,FUN=sum)
```

Output:

```
     Phylum Abundance
1   Bacteroidetes        40
2      Firmicutes        34
3  Proteobacteria         6
4 Verrucomicrobia         2
```

Comment: Thank you for offering different alternatives. It was a shorter and faster solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(Phylum = c("Bacteroidetes","Firmicutes","Proteobacteria","Firmicutes","Firmicutes","Bacteroidetes","Proteobacteria","Bacteroidetes","Verrucomicrobia","Bacteroidetes"),
                 Abundance = c(12,4,3,21,9,15,3,8,2,5))

df %>% 
  group_by(Phylum) %>% 
  summarize(Abundance = sum(Abundance)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: I really thank you for solving my problem. I tried everything in the dplyr package but didn't know there was ungroup().